# i don't know why i get this error in my console even if my site is just working fine, "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I am using React function based component and this is a app in which i add an api to fetch News and display inside my site. Everything is working fine, but this error "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key" in console is so annoying.
Please Help me to get rid of this problem.

again i want to say, the app is working fine and the error is only lies in Console.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import NewsItem from "./NewsItem";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";
const News =(props)=>{

  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState([true])
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const [totalResults, setTotalResults] = useState(0)

  const capitalizeFirstLetter=(string)=> {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }
  //Here we put the link of our API
  const updateNews = async ()=> {
    props.setProgress(10);
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${props.country}&category=${props.category}&apiKey=${props.apiKey}&page=${page}&pageSize=${props.pageSize}`; //api url, i add page and page size later
    setLoading(true)
    let data = await fetch(url); //using fetch api
    props.setProgress(50);
    let parsedData = await data.json(); //converting
    props.setProgress(70);
    setArticles(parsedData.articles)
    setTotalResults(parsedData.totalResults)
    setLoading(false)
    props.setProgress(100);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    updateNews();
    document.title = `${capitalizeFirstLetter(props.category)} - NewsMonk`;

  }, [])
  const fetchMoreData = async () => {//code taken from codesandbox.com
    setPage(page+1)
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${props.country}&category=${props.category}&apiKey=${props.apiKey}&page=${page}&pageSize=${props.pageSize}`; //api url, i add page and page size later
    let data = await fetch(url); //using fetch api
    let parsedData = await data.json(); //converting
    setArticles(articles.concat(parsedData.articles))
    setTotalResults(parsedData.totalResults)  
    setLoading(false)
  };
    return (
      <>
          <h1 className="text-center" style={{ margin: "35px" }}>
            NewsMonk - Top {capitalizeFirstLetter(props.category)} Headlines
          </h1>
          {loading && <Spinner />}
          <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={articles.length} next={fetchMoreData} hasMore={articles.length!==totalResults}>
          <div className="container">

          <div className="row">
            
            {articles.map((element) => {
                  return <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
                    <NewsItem title={element.title ? element.title: ""} description={element.description ? element.description: ""} imageUrl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl={element.url} author={element.author} date={element.publishedAt} source={element.source.name} bCol={"bg-danger"}
                    />
                    {/* 
                     if you want to slice the text then we have to use the slice functionality
                     ?element.description.slice(0, 77):" "
                     ?element.title.slice(0, 55):" "
                     */}
                  </div>
              })}
          </div>
          </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </>
    );
}

News.defaultProps = {
  country: "in",
  pageSize: 6,
  title: "No Title Available",
  category: "general",
};
News.propTypes = {
  country: PropTypes.string,
  pageSize: PropTypes.number,
  category: PropTypes.string,
};
export default News;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error has to do with your map, which is creating a looped structure of your elements. Since the mapped elements in the loop are siblings, then React will need each key prop to be unique.

In short, `element.url` does not provide a unique key string in your case. You'll need to figure out a way to pass unique identifiers as your key prop. If your articles have an ID or something else that is unique, use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your `map` loop:

```
        {articles.map((element) => {
              return <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
                <NewsItem title={element.title ? element.title: ""} description={element.description ? element.description: ""} imageUrl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl={element.url} author={element.author} date={element.publishedAt} source={element.source.name} bCol={"bg-danger"}
                />
                {/* 
                 if you want to slice the text then we have to use the slice functionality
                 ?element.description.slice(0, 77):" "
                 ?element.title.slice(0, 55):" "
                 */}
              </div>
          })}
```

You're setting the `key` as `element.url` (`key={element.url}`). Apparently, it seems that the URL is repeated so some of your items are sharing the same key when it should be unique.

Of course, it's a console warning (doesn't block or break the rendering) but ideally, you should remove it since the key helps React to detect what elements have changed on a list, as you can see in their [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
> removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
> the elements of a stable identity:

You can easily get rid of the warning by assigning a unique value, such as the `title`, or one of the multiple props you are drilling down:

```
    {articles.map((element, index) => {
          return <div className="col-md-4" key={element.title}>
            <NewsItem title={element.title ? element.title: ""} description={element.description ? element.description: ""} imageUrl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl={element.url} author={element.author} date={element.publishedAt} source={element.source.name} bCol={"bg-danger"}
            />
            {/* 
             if you want to slice the text then we have to use the slice functionality
             ?element.description.slice(0, 77):" "
             ?element.title.slice(0, 55):" "
             */}
          </div>
      })}
```

If you can't ensure that none of the values are unique, you can use the index of the loop, despite it's not a good practice.

Your `NewsItem` component is receiving a lot of props, which makes your code less maintainable than something simpler as:

```
    {articles.map((element) => {
          return <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
             <NewsItem {...element} bCol={"bg-danger"} />
          </div>
      })}
```

But in this case, you'll need to treat/alias your data in the `NewsItem` component. `element` contains all your props so you can drill all the object down and treat there what you need (slicing, setting default values, etc).